# Determine whether the direction of a line segment is clockwise or anti clockwise

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, geometry

I have a list of 2D points (x1,y1),(x2,y2)......(Xn,Yn) representing a curved segment, is there any formula to determine whether the direction of drawing that segment is clockwise or anti clockwise ?

any help is appreciated

Comment: How can a segment have a clockwise/counter-clokwise direction? What is the exact definition?

Comment: the segment is a curved part of a handwritten arabic character

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data?

Comment: This is very ambiguous.  Consider a half-moon shape.  You could trace the curve either clockwise or anti-clockwise.  This is very ill-formed.

Comment: @rayryeng I guess _that_'s what he wants to detect: how the shape is traced. The order of the points in the list would be different in each case

Comment: @LuisMendo - Ok I get it.  One thing you could possibly do is given the curve, find its centre of mass.  Once you do this, find the angle that each point along the curve makes with this centre of mass.  After this, use `diff` and see the neighbouring differences between the points.  If the `diff` elements for each element in this output vector are positive, this could be considered as clockwise, where if it were negative, this could be considered as anti-clockwise.  Perhaps make a histogram of positive and negative occurrences and whichever bin has the higher count, that's the direction chosen

Comment: @Yvon - I agree.  Ahmed: if you could provide some example points that we can work with, it'll make our lives easier.

Comment: Ahmed: One question - Would this curved surface **ever be closed** (i.e. a circle)?  If it is, then my method will not work as it will be highly ambiguous when you start approaching where the two ends meet.

Comment: @rayryeng no it is not closed, it could be a half moon, quarter or any shape like that but never closed

Comment: @rayryeng I was typing my answer and then saw your comment. I think my answer is more or less what you suggested

Comment: @rayryeng how about tracing it in Cartesian coordinates? 1) no need to find center of mass 2) no need to smooth the angle. Just roughly count the moving trends.

Comment: @rayryeng I think the ambiguity you refer to can be removed by __unwrapping the phase__ (provided sampling represented by the points is sufficiently fine). That's what I've done in my answer.

Comment: @LuisMendo - Correct.  Forgot about `unwrap`.  Good spot!

Comment: @ahmedabobakr - In that case, Luis Mendo's (basically a modified version of my) approach will work.  Good luck!

Comment: @Yvon - That may not work depending on the curve.  For example, consider a question mark.  There is a half moon, which is drawn clockwise, but then there is a horizontal segment that moves in the opposite direction towards the starting point.  By tracing it in Cartesian co-ordinates, we would detect both a CW and CCW change, whereas if you calculated the angles with the centre of mass, this would predominantly be signified as clockwise.  Still a good thing to suggest!

Comment: @rayryeng Another approach: draw a line from starting point to ending point. This line is indeed a vector. A CW curve has most of its part on RHS of this line. For CCW, left.

Comment: @Yvon - Hm! Another interesting approach.  Potential caveat.  Consider a half moon drawn from +90 degrees to -90 degrees.  This would draw a vertical line from the top of the curve, to the bottom of the curve.  Using this criteria, we would not be sure what direction this half-moon was drawn in by looking at the Cartesian points of the beginning and end.

Comment: @rayryeng No! Your example is pretty typical. For a CCW one, its center of mass is on the LHS of the vector. For CW, RHS. Because it's a vector rather than a line, we can always tell left or right.

Comment: @Yvon - Oh yes.  I misunderstood your example completely.  This could work.  Try it out, then post it as an additional answer.  I'd like to see this work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach. It should work reasonably well if the sampling of the line represented by your list of points is uniform and smooth enough, and if the line is sufficiently simple.

1. Subtract the mean to "center" the line.
2. Convert to polar coordinates to get the angle.
3. Unwrap the angle, to make sure its increments are meaningful.
4. Check if total increment is possitive or negative.

I'm assuming you have the data in `x` and `y` vectors.

```
theta = cart2pol(x-mean(x), y-mean(y)); %// steps 1 and 2
theta = unwrap(theta); %// step 3
clockwise = theta(end)<theta(1); %// step 4. Gives 1 if CW, 0 if ACW
```

This only considers the *integrated* effect of all points. It  doesn't tell you if there are "kinks" or sections with different directions of turn along the way.

A possible improvement would be to replace the average of `x` and `y` by some kind of integral. The reason is: if sampling is denser in a region the average will be biased towards that, whereas the integral wouldn't.

Comment: Yup... this is pretty much the suggested approach that I wrote!  Very nice.  I decided to bin all of the differences and see which sign had the higher count, and that's the one I would choose.  This is still a good approach.

Comment: luis i tried your approach and it works :) thaaank you for your help
@rayryeng your help is much appreciated thank you too

Comment: @LuisMendo - I'm favouriting this post, mainly because of the collaboration between different SO users (Yvon, you and myself) to ultimately come up with an answer that worked for the OP.  Thanks!

Comment: @ahmedabobakr - You are very welcome.  Glad we could help you solve this problem!

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry if I (inadvertently) stole your approach. I was busy preparing my answer and totally unaware that you had proposed the same in your comments

Comment: @LuisMendo - That's no problem at all.  To be honest, I wasn't sure if my approach would work.  Seeing that you posted an answer, and the OP accepting it is confirmation that what I had in my mind worked.  Reputation points are only secondary.  I'm mostly here to help people, and this post and collaboration is a testament to that.

Answer (score 8):

Alternately, you can use a bit of linear algebra. If you have three points a, b, and c, in that order, then do the following:

```
 1)  create the vectors u = (b-a) = (b.x-a.x,b.y-a.y) and v = (c-b) ...
 2) calculate the cross product uxv = u.x*v.y-u.y*v.x
 3) if uxv is -ve then a-b-c is curving in clockwise direction (and vice-versa).
```

by following a longer curve along in the same manner, you can even detect when as 's'-shaped curve changes from clockwise to anticlockwise, if that is useful.

Comment: For me it's the best solution by far. +1

Comment: @seb - Never mind.  I misread the algorithm.  I'm going to delete my comment as it's nonsense.

Comment: @Penguino: i have N points, i tried your approach but because i have N points i did summation on the result of the cross product of each two successive diff vectors, is that correct ?

Comment: @ahmed: Yes, do something like x1=diff(x) y1=diff(y), then X-product of all consecutive elements of x1 y1

Comment: @ahmed Yep - if the curve is locally-clockwise along its entire length then you will get all -ve cross products, so summing is fine. But if the curve has the same direction of curvature along its entire length, you can save time by just doing the test on the first three points.

Answer (score 3):

Now this is my approach, as mentioned in a comment to the question -

> Another approach: draw a line from starting point to ending point. This line is indeed a vector. A CW curve has most of its part on RHS of this line. For CCW, left.

I wrote a sample code to elaborate this idea. Most of the explanation can be found in comments in the code.

```
clear;clc;close all

%% draw a spiral curve
N = 30;
theta = linspace(0,pi/2,N); % a CCW curve
rho = linspace(1,.5,N);
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta,rho);
clearvars theta rho N

plot(x,y);
hold on

%% find "the vector"
vec(:,:,1) = [x(1), y(1); x(end), y(end)]; % "the vector"

scatter(x(1),y(1), 200,'s','r','fill') % square is the starting point
scatter(x(end),y(end), 200,'^','r','fill') % triangle is the ending point
line(vec(:,1,1), vec(:,2,1), 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', 'r')

%% find center of mass
com = [mean(x), mean(y)]; % center of mass

vec(:,:,2) = [x(1), y(1); com]; % secondary vector (start -> com)

scatter(com(1), com(2), 200,'d','k','fill') % diamond is the com
line(vec(:,1,2), vec(:,2,2), 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', 'k')

%% find rotation angle
dif = diff(vec,1,1);
[ang, ~] = cart2pol(reshape(dif(1,1,:),1,[]), reshape(dif(1,2,:),1,[]));
clearvars dif

% now you can tell the answer by the rotation angle
if ( diff(ang)>0 )
    disp('CW!')
else
    disp('CCW!')
end
```

One can always tell on which side of the directed line (*the vector*) a point is, by comparing two vectors, namely, rotating vector [starting point -> center of mass] to the vector [starting point -> ending point], and then comparing the rotation angle to 0. A few seconds of mind-animating can help understand.

Comment: Not useless!  +1 from me... in about 22 minutes.  I've reached my maximum amount of votes for today.