# Find convex shapes in bitmap-like data

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Datastructure:
- Assume a grid of cells. Each cell knows its right, top, left, bottom neighbour.
- A cell is either on or off or in other words black or white. Two states.
- A cell if connected to the neighbour cell if they are in the same state - both white for example

I want to find out if connected cells form a convex shape. For one state only - but i guess this should not matter.

Basic idea:
Iterate over the grid and paint IDs into an array[grid.width][grid.length] with a flood fill algorithm.

Problem:
How do i probably know that a area of connected cells is convex and not concav with this information.

I am searching for a algorithm or a definition wich tells me if a connected set of cells is concav or convex based on the knowledge of their neighbours.

Example - red concav, blue convex:
[Concav vs. convex](http://www.zentralnorden.com/temp/cc_cv.png)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at convex hull algorithms:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms

You could compute the convex hull for each ID and check for discrepancies between the original shape and the computed convex shape.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to

```
1) identify the boundary points of each shape (i.e. the cells that are in contact with cells of another colour) 
2) trace along them using the cross-product to check if local curvature changes sign at any point on the boundary
```

(see, for example [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252664/determine-whether-the-direction-of-a-line-segment-is-clockwise-or-anti-clockwise/25253151#25253151))

But I think it is important for you to define exactly what you mean by convex. If you consider each cell as a representation of a pixel in a bitmap then any edge that is not either horizontal or vertical will contain sections that are locally concave. Consider, for example a connected shape consisting the cells (0,0), (0,1) and (1,0). Does this shape represent a triangle (and therefore is convex), or an 'L' an therefore is concave?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps i should have been clearer. Your example would be convex for me. See the link in my question.