# which point is at anti clockwise direction

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

I have given group of poings where p0 is center point.

[image]

Here what i want to find it with respect to line p0p3 which line either p0p1 or p0p2 is anticlockwise. or is analysed first when rotated anti clockwise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252664/determine-whether-the-direction-of-a-line-segment-is-clockwise-or-anti-clockwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cross product 2D

You can use the cross product of two vectors to find the direction (CW or CCW).

Eg 3 points `[p1, p2, p3]` defining 2 line `{p1, p2}` and `{p1, p3}`...

```
P1 = {x:?, y:?}
P2 = {x:?, y:?}
P3 = {x:?, y:?}
```

Get the two vectors for `p1` to `p2` and `p1` to `p3`...

```
vx1 = p2.x - p1.x
vy1 = p2.y - p1.y

vx2 = p3.x - p1.x
vy2 = p3.y - p1.y
```

Get the cross product of the vectors...

```
cross = vx1 * vy2 - vy1 * vx2
```

OR in one step...

```
cross = (p2.x - p1.x) * (p3.y - p1.y) - (p2.y - p1.y) * (p3.x - p1.x)
```

The point `p3` is CW if `cross` is positive, parallel if `cross` is zero and CCW if `cross` is negative

```
if cross > 0 
   dir = "clockwise"
else if cross == 0
   dir = "parallel"
else 
   dir = "counter-clockwise"
```

### Cross product to get angle

You can also get the angle between the vectors if you normalize the vectors

```
length1 = sqrt(vx1 * vx1 + vy1 * vy1)
vx1 /= length1
vy1 /= length1

length2 = sqrt(vx2 * vx2 + vy2 * vy2)
vx2 /= length2
vy2 /= length2
```

The inverse sin of the cross product is the angle in the range -Pi/2 (-90deg) to Pi/2 (90deg) with positive CW and negative CCW

```
angle = asin(vx1 * vy2 - vy1 * vx2)
```

Comment: thanks. this is d best answer i can possible think of.